# jQuery Syntax in Rails Interactive Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

So I'm building an interactive form for a rails project and I'm unsure how to list multiple jQuery functions in the same file.  Every time I try to add a second set of code language, it breaks the whole file.

Here's the rails code.

```
<div id="countertype" class="form-group" align="left">
  <%= f.label :countertype_id, "What type of countertop material do you need?" %></br>
  <%= f.collection_select :countertype_id, Countertype.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Select Your Material" }, class: "input-sm"  %>
</div>
```

If the user selects option id 1 from the above field, which is called "granite", the granitecolor select field shows.  Same would work for marble, soapstone, etc.

Here's a field select that I would like to show:

```
<div id="granitecolor" align="left" class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :granitecolor_id, "What granite color pattern do you want?" %></br>
  <%= f.select :granitecolor_id, options_for_select(@granitecolors.map{ |g| [g.name, g.id, {'data-img-src'=>g.url}]}) %>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div id="marblecolor" align="left" class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :marblecolor_id, "What marble color pattern do you want?" %></br>
  <%= f.select :marblecolor_id, options_for_select(@marblecolors.map{ |m| [m.name, m.id, {'data-img-src'=>m.url}] }) %>
</div>
```

Here's what I have now in my jQuery file and it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("select:not(#countertop_countertype_id)").val('0').imagepicker({
      show_label:   true,
      clicked:function(){

        console.log($(this).find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").data('img-src'));

      }
    });

});
```

Here's what I'd like to add (or a variation of this).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  toggleFields();
  $("#countertype").change(function () {
    toggleFields();
  });

});

function toggleFields() {
  if ($("#countertype").val() = 1 )
     $("#granitecolor").show();
  elseif
     ($("#countertype").val() = 2 )
     $("#marblecolor").show();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than I thought.  I just posted the entire jQuery code right after the first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("select:not(#countertop_countertype_id)").val('0').imagepicker({
     show_label:   true,
     clicked:function(){

    console.log($(this).find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").data('img-src'));

    }
  });

});   

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#granitecolor').hide();
    $('#marblecolor').hide();

    $('#countertype').change(function () {
        if ($('#countertype option:selected').text() == "Granite"){
            $('#granitecolor').show();
            $('#marblecolor').hide();

        }
        else if ($('#countertype option:selected').text() == "Marble"){
            $('#granitecolor').hide();
            $('#marblecolor').show();

        }
        else if ($('#countertype option:selected').text() == "Soapstone"){
            $('#granitecolor').hide();
            $('#marblecolor').hide();

        }
    }); 
});
```